# Login to Admin Pages

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, admin

I have created a website, and wanted to make my admin pages where you have to log in to view them. I have no clue how to do this, was considering doing this in PHP or JS, whatever is easiest.

Comment: what did you use to create your website? `was considering doing this in PHP or JS` you're gonna be needing both. You see, you treat it as a whole different website but for yourself only, and it's connected to the same database as your frontend website

Comment: Well, if you want to stick with JS for server side, then you can use NodeJS else go with PHP! There's no such thing as easiest. It solely depends on you.

Comment: I've essentially done most of front end with html with minor things in JS.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking for roles. When creating a new user specify a user role ex: customer,admin etc.

When you make the login script set a new Session with the user role. 
Example:   if username and password are correct

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['user_role']=$role;


In admin page use : 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])){
if($_SESSION['user_role']=='admin'){
//User role is admin he can access that page

}else{
//user role is not admin, he can not access that page
}

}else{
header("Location: login.php");
}
```